# LINQ and group by data nested within a structure

Tags: c#, linq, nested

I have a structure that roughly looks like this:

```
List<ProductLine> -> ID
                     Name
                     ...
                     List<LineOfBusiness> -> ID
                                             Name
                                             ...
                                             List<Watchlist> -> ID
                                                                Name
                                                                ReportCount
```

A Watchlist can exist under multiple LoBs but the ReportCount will only be for the count of reports that exist under that LoB for that WatchList.  I need them in the structure this way because the count of how many reports exist within a LoB for a given Watchlist is important elsewhere.

What I need to do is get a list of the distinct WatchLists (grouped based on ID) and have the ReportCount be the SUM of that watchlist's ReportCount across all LoBs.  I can't quite get the nested select logic to work right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The technique to flatten a hierarchical structure is to use the `SelectMany` method. You need something like this:

```
var result = mainList.SelectMany(x => x.LineOfBusinessList)
                     .SelectMany(lob => lob.Watchlists)
                     .GroupBy(wl => wl.ID)
                     .Select(g => new { 
                            WatchlistID = g.Key,
                            WatchlistName = g.First().Name,
                            ReportCount = g.Sum(item => item.ReportCount)  
                     });
```

The first `SelectMany` call will transform the original list to sequence of all `LineOfBusiness` objects in all items. The second `SelectMany` call will transform a sequence of `LineOfBusiness` objects to a sequence containing all `Watchlist` objects it them. Then you group these `Watchlist`s by they `ID` and perform the actual query on them.

Comment: the g.Key.ID does not work, nor does the g.Key.Name.  I assume I can select the WatchlistID by asking for g.Key, but then how would I get the name?

Comment: Parrots: Oops. Yeah, you are right. I was originally thinking that Watchlist has it's own unique ID and you are checking Equals... Actually, you are not grouping by Name, so the query thinks names can be different. Since you know that the name is unique, just use g.First().Name to get it.