# Querying using LINQ nested data structure and returning nested groups

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094724/linq-and-group-by-data-nested-within-a-structure) but for a data structure that has an unknown level of nesting? Is addition, though I believe this was the case in the other question also, every level has more than one entry (assume this though it could have only one, or zero).

In addition, is there a good way to store such a data structure such that the parent of every object can be easily found? I was thinking of something like a jagged array, but that seems hard to generate at runtime, as I do not know how deep the nesting is. Something with a structure like a treeview would be ideal, but I don't want to implement a control if I will just be using it for data storage, and not for the visual part.

As a last resort, I was thinking of writing my own class to store the data, but don't want to do that if I don't have to.

Comment: Unknown level of nesting? That's sounds potentially cpu-harmful....

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not worse than 20, and certainly not higher than  30 (though in theory it could be). I am reading this out of a text file though, so its not that bad.

Comment: Can you show us how exactly (i.e. code) does the data structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an n-ary tree with parent references?

```
class Node
{
    public Node Parent { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; }
}

IEnumerable<Node> Flatten(Node node)
{
    yield return node;
    foreach (var child in node.Children)
    {
        yield return Flatten(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the data into that structure (I need a reverse of the Flatten, not the Flatten itself)?

Comment: @soandos: depends on how your data look like.

Comment: @dbt, do you have an way to do this?